# How to check if line goes through point with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, intersection

I have a line representing a bus line and a stop representing a bus stop
[image]

The following sample data represents the problem

```
LINESTRING(-70.65357957000000511 -33.42323483999999922, -70.65181886999999961 -33.4232948200000024)
POINT(-70.65199072011725434 -33.42328896575632768)
```

The point was create with the [Shapely interpolate method](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.interpolate).

Now I want to test if the line goes through the bus stop.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
ST_Intersects(
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-70.65357957000000511 -33.42323483999999922, -70.65181886999999961 -33.4232948200000024)'),
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-70.65199072011725434 -33.42328896575632768)'))
```

This returns `false`. Is it possible with PostGIS to find out if the line crosses the point?

As a workaround I was thinking to buffer the points, but I am hoping for a cleaner solution.

---

Overall I want to do a spatial join, joining the lines id to the bus stops.

```
select lines.ogc_fid, stops.wkb_geometry from lines, stops WHERE ST_Intersects  (lines.wkb_geometry, stops.wkb_geometry)
```

---

**UPDATE**:
I realised the points are simply not on the line. I zoomed in really far and the point is next to the line, not on the line. So only a solution like buffer will work.

Comment: I think it is a topology process. Give us more information about the version of PostGIs used.

Comment: I am using ```POSTGIS="2.1.5 r13152" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.9.2" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER```

Comment: Perhaps you could post an actual LineString and Point that you think should intersect, but for which you get no results.

Comment: @JohnBarça I added some sample data. Your question made me realise that it is not possible. I zoomed really far into the sample data, and the point actually is not on the line. So a workaround is necessary.

Comment: Glad you got a solution. You can probably use ST_Distance for more efficient use of index than you will get from buffering.

Comment: @JohnBarça I doubt ST_Distance uses spatial indexes.

Comment: @Zimmi, sorry, ST_DWithin, my bad. Much more efficient than Buffer.

Comment: @JohnBarça now you're right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might solve this issue by creating a buffer out of your linestrings as it is possible your lines are not going through the points precisely.

`SELECT points.id FROM points JOIN lines on ST_Intersects(points.geom, ST_Buffer(lines.geom, number));`

---

Solution using ST_DWithin() might be a better option (suggested by @JohnBarca in a comment).

Comment: Thanks @zimmi for the answer. Though I am looking for a solution without buffer, since this might cause wrong intersections.

Comment: How about finding the nearest line to each point then? 

update:
~~Which will efficiently crash at crossings I suppose~~